# Updating multiple servers on Save with Dreamweaver CC 2017

Tags: adobe, dreamweaver

I have multiple servers on AWS and I want to keep them all exactly the same.  I can establish a Remote server and a Testing server in Dreamweaver and have it automatically upload changed files whenever I save a file, but it only uploads to the Remote server, not the Testing server.  I have the "Automatically push files to testing server" checkbox checked, but it doesn't do it.

There may come a time when I have more than just two servers I want to keep updated.  You'd think that I could set up several servers in the Site Manager and have the changed file pushed to multiple servers on Save.

I tried WinSCP, and that monitors a directory for any change and updates the server, but will only do it for one server per instance, which mostly fulfills my need, but you'd think you could set this up in Dreamweaver.

Am I missing something?  Better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I now use WinSCP and have it monitor folders for changes and upload them.  I just open up more than one instance of it to upload to multiple servers when I change something.

Answer (score 0):

Dreamweaver "Push to testing server" actually uploads on Remote server only. There is no way to save on 2 servers. You must use second programs/scripts for that job.